# How to extend my concrete lan on the vpn space offered by Hamachi?

Tags: networking, vpn, hamachi

I have my home LAN served by a cheap wifi router connected to the Internet through an ADSL connection. Then I have several devices linked to the LAN both through ethernet cables and wireless. Devices include NAS and Windows computers. They all share the same subnet and everything work as expected.

Then I have a similar setup in my business place and I'd like to bridge the two separated networks through a free tunneling service like Hamachi. As far as I experienced in the past all I could do was simply connecting two hosts on the same VPN. Now I want to bridge two entire LAN with that same tunnel and make possible for each host to eventually reach hosts sitting on the other LAN.

Does anyone know if this is even possible? Does Hamachi offer such a service? Do I need to touch some special settings? Or please if you have better solution than Hamachi just point me to the correct path?

P.S.: there's no firewall on both LAN and they both link mainly Windows 7 machines (in one case even a macbook but that's not important now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd either be looking to configure each individual device with Hamachi, or configuring your routers for a VPN. Hamachi cannot be configured on a router.

The advantage to setting up your own VPN with your routers is that the two networks will see each other much more seamlessly. You could even set up your printers to be accessible between locations.

The disadvantage is that it is rather involved and may require special equipment depending on your needs and expertise. Not all routers come with VPN capabilities. If I were in your shoes, I'd buy myself a pair of [Linksys WRT-54GL](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833124190), flash them with [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), find a dynamic DNS service to manage the ever-changing IP addresses provided by your ISP, and then [configure one router as a server](http://www.howtogeek.com/51772/how-to-setup-a-vpn-server-using-a-dd-wrt-router/) and the other one [as a client](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/OpenVPN#GUI:_Client_Mode).

Comment: Unfortunately the main reason to share the business lan on a vpn was just to get access to the nas from the home lan. I cannot setup hamachi directly on nas. I wished a software trick on windows to bridge the lans over the hamachi virtual adapter. Your suggestion about DD-WRT seems much interesting and I want to investigate further. Anyway I'm afraid I've not public ip at all and really need an intermediate public host to build the tunnel. Your help was much appreciated, if anyone cannot give further details in a while, I'll choose yours as the final answer.

Comment: I'm sure there's several ways you could access the NAS through the Windows box + Hamachi. It might be as simple as mapping it as a network drive then sharing it through the Windows machine to the other computers on your Hamachi network. I'm not sure about the efficiency of this however... For better performance you might want to configure your NAS for iSCSI. It's hard to tell as I'm not familiar with Hamachi.